# Replacing default hibernate method to s2disk

Tags: 11.10, hibernate, default

I have installed uswsusp module with 'sudo apt-get install uswsusp'. Now I am trying to replace the default hibernate method (as launched from the menu) with s2disk. I found information that I am to edit this file:

```
/usr/lib/hal/scripts/linux/hal-system-power-suspend-linux
```

Unfortunately the path '/usr/lib/hal' does not exist in my system. Also, the directory '/etc/pm/config.d/' exists, but is empty, and creating there a file '00_sleep-module' did not help. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks !! A lot, that worked perfect. I was able to get s2disk to hibernate my Toshiba C640, but not restore it. By updating **/etc/pm/config.d/00sleep_module** and purging **cryptsetup** as per post on [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/110920/cannot-resume-from-hibernate-s2disk) , things started working well.

Although waking from hibernate Grub 2 looks like something is wrong as it is stuck
on background for few seconds. Maybe its just grub or large 4 GB ram snapshot 
being loaded from disk. I will have to check.

Also, my LAN connection came back. I had serious doubts about it, since I had to
custom compile Atheros Fast Ethernet card module into Kernel.

I am using kernel **3.2.0-27-generic** with Ubuntu 12.04 LTs on Toshiba Satellite C640 Hardware. Steps I have followed

```
sudo nano /etc/pm/config.d/00sleep_module
```

If you never touched this file OOTB it should be entirely commented. Please read it entirely. Add following line to end of file

```
SLEEP_MODULE="uswsusp"
```

Finally purge cryptsetup, I am not sure about this step, it may or may not help

```
sudo apt-get purge cryptsetup
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a file called `module` in `/etc/pm/config.d/module` if not already there and add

`SLEEP_MODULE=uswsusp`

inorder to work with `pm-utils`

I think you should also go through the configuration part given in the link below.

[Source](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Uswsusp#With_pm-utils)

Comment: I'm sorry, it didn't work out, even though I changed privileges of the file to 755 and restarted the machine to pick up changes. The most annoying feature of the old hibernate is that it asks for password on resume.

The link does not provide configuration instruction.

Comment: All settings in /etc/pm/config.d/module, /etc/pm/config.d/config and even /usr/lib/pm-utils/defaults seem to be ignored. I might ask another (more specific) question or report a bug if it continues this way.

Answer (score 1):

After reinstalling 11.10 from scratch, s2disk is the default option.