# Cannot resume from hibernate (s2disk)

Tags: power-management, hibernate, resume

I seem to be able to hibernate OK using `s2disk`, but when I switch the laptop back on, it seems to hang half-way through the "resuming" menu.  The splash screen looks healthy, it seems to be trying to resume from the correct disk, but it hangs about half-way through, with three little pips.

One great help would be - *where can I find the logs, and how do I get more verbose ones?*

There is some info in `/var/log/pm-suspend.log`, but that all seems fine, just lots of `hibernate: success` messages...

How do I switch on more verbose logging in s2disk?  And what about the resume process, where are the logs for that, and how can I make them more detailed?

Background: the standard Ubuntu hibernate wouldn't work, so I've install `uswusp` and its associated tools - `s2disk` etc.  That initially made things worse, but a fair amount of fiddling with its config, my swap size and so on seem to have got it at least seemingly successfully suspending...

[update] some config info:

RAM: 8GB
swap space: 8.63GiB (NB i did try increasing swap to 16GB, didn't help)

```
$ sudo blkid
/dev/sda: TYPE="isw_raid_member" 
/dev/zram0: UUID="45e58d74-be57-4ad4-95de-217e9ba7d087" TYPE="swap" 
/dev/sdb: TYPE="isw_raid_member" 
/dev/mapper/isw_dgibfidibf_Volume0p1: LABEL="Ubuntu" UUID="7ca86fcb-a969-45d5-b67f-fe29bc568f4d" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/mapper/isw_dgibfidibf_Volume0p2: LABEL="System Reserved" UUID="2A1A38861A3850D5" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/mapper/isw_dgibfidibf_Volume0p3: LABEL="Windows" UUID="FE6C39286C38DD59" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/mapper/isw_dgibfidibf_Volume0p5: UUID="dfb8af38-acf1-42be-be18-131d326a21ff" TYPE="swap" 
/dev/mapper/isw_dgibfidibf_Volume0p6: LABEL="SHARED" UUID="10BA-FE58" TYPE="vfat" 

$ cat /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume
RESUME=/dev/mapper/isw_dgibfidibf_Volume0p5
```

[update 2] - have followed instructions at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingKernelSuspendHibernateResume
and submitted a bug report:  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/hibernate/+bug/987109

Comment: Please edit your question to contain the following: Size of RAM, size of swap partition, output of `sudo blkid`, and content of `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume`.

Answer (score 1):

try removing cryptsetup from your system, worked for me.

Comment: nope... thx for trying tho!

Answer (score 0):

This answer may not be helpful for around 7 days, but I had a similar problem with hibernate and sleep and when I upgraded to Ubuntu 12.04 Beta all issues were solved. So I'd suggest either simply waiting till April 26th and upgrade then or Installing Ubuntu 12.04 Beta.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Though you would need to reenable it as hibernate is disabled by default in 12.04 as far as I know. Would be interesting to know what RAM and swap you actually have.

Comment: Good point I hadn't even noticed, the last time I hibernated must have been before they changed that! Also I have 1GB RAM and 2GB swap :)

Comment: nope, just upgraded to 12.04 beta yesterday, and if anything hibernate is even worse - it doesn't even get as far as shutting down now, just sticks at `freezing processes`